# Absolute value manipulation

Tags: absolute-value

Is it always true to say that if $|a|=b$ then $a=\pm b$ or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's true for real numbers:  $|a|=\pm a$ so if $|a|=b$ then $\pm a=b$ so $a=\pm b$

Comment: or if $|a|=b$ then $a^2=b^2$ so $a=\pm b$

Answer (score 0):

Absolute value is defined as (if we talk about $a\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e real numbers):

$$|a| = \begin{cases}{a} & a\geq0 \\ {-a} & a<0 \end{cases}$$

Think of it as the distance of $a$ from $0$.

So for example, $|-5|=5, |6|=6$. So if we write $b=|a|$ we want to say "$b$ is in the same distance from $0$ as $a$". Note that absolute value is always a non negative number (because negative distance doesn't make sense).

For more information, take a look at [Absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true.

$|a|= a$ or $-a$,  so, if $|a|=b$, then $b=a$ or $-a$, which means $a=b$ or $-b$.